# Passing and printing Arraylist from servlet to Jsp with JSTL

Tags: jsp, servlets, arraylist, jstl

How can i pass an arraylist with objects from servlet to Jsp and then print their attributes using Jstl?
For example:

```
   **// Servlet side//** 

     Arraylist lala = new Arraylist; 
     object asd = new object(id,name,age); 
     lala.add(asd); 

 **//Jsp side//** 

     //print lala[1].id
     //print lala[1].name
     //print lala[1].age
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set an attribute on the `HttpServletRequest` object. In your servlet:

```
req.setAttribute("myList", yourArrayList);
```

In your jsp page you can access it with el like this:

```
${requestScope.myList}
```

To iterate over your `ArrayList` using jstl, you could use the `<c:forEach>` tag. Like this:

```
<c:forEach var="asd" items="${requestScope.myList}">
    <%-- This calls the getId() method on your asd object --%>
    <c:out value="${asd.id}"/>
    <%-- This calls the getName() method on your asd object --%>
    <c:out value="${asd.name}"/>
    <%-- This calls the getAge() method on your asd object --%>
    <c:out value="${asd.age}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Hi Asaph, following you code, I tried to implement it in html table but its showing me only last element of the arraylist. Can you please explain more in such case??